# How to respond (comment/answer) to questions related to scraping of websites where scraping is against their ToS?

Tags: discussion, support, facebook

How to respond (comment / answer) to questions related to scrapping of websites where scraping is against their ToS?

Recently I have come across a lot of questions relating to scraping of [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/), Ebay, etc where as scraping those sites is against their ToS. Some of the websites does provide APIs to perform automated actions. But question askers seems to be reluctant to use APIs.

A couple of example :

- [How to make post on Facebook using Selenium Webdriver + Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48466715/how-to-make-post-on-facebook-using-selenium-webdriver-java)
- [Selenium how to find and click Business Manager option on Facebook Logout Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48513277/selenium-how-to-find-and-click-business-manager-option-on-facebook-logout-menu)

So how should be our approach towards those questions?

- Should we completely ignore those questions?
- Should we provide a comment and back-out?
- Should we raise a flag?

Comment: If you found question on web crawling that *is not duplicate* feel free to edit out questionable content/url to make it into high quality unique non-controversial question... In most other cases downvote is likely enough as pretty much every aspect of scraping already covered multiple times on SO and everywhere else.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This comment clears all of my queries.